# TestNG Android Unit Tests, Stub! Exception

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, testng, robolectric

I am getting "java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!" and it is because android.jar contains only stub implementation of the classes.  I will not be running the tests in an emulator.  [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/) works with JUnit but it does not appear to work with TestNG.  Is it possible to run TestNG classes without an android emulator?  All I need is a [Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) and I would like to use [MockContext](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/mock/MockContext.html) but every method is a Stub! exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it doesn't work out of the box.

The problem is that you need a test runner. If this was a JUnit test, you would use `@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)`, but with TestNG, you can't easily do that.